# Waiting for createWriteStream in KOAJS before exiting

Tags: javascript, generator, koa

I know of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23852948/wait-for-async-process-to-finish-before-redirect-in-koajs) question, but my need is a little different.

I'm trying to download multiple images but cannot prevent the app from exiting before the process is complete.  I've gone through quite a few iterations, this is where I'm at currently:

```
router
.post('/', koaBody(), function *() {
    var images = [];
    //console.log(this.request.body.fields);
    if (this.request.body.fields) {
        images = this.request.body.fields['images'];
        imageCount = images.length;
    } else {
        this.status = 500;
        return;
    }

    var url = 'https://www.google.ca/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png';
    var filepath = '../images/image_1.png';

    var pipeRequest = function (url, filepath) {
        return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            request.get(url)
                .pipe(fs.createWriteStream(filepath))
                .on('finish', function () {
                    console.log('piped');
                });
        });
    };

    co(function*() {
        yield pipeRequest(url, filepath);
    }).then(function () {
        console.log('done co-func');
    }).catch(function (err) {
        return console.error(err);
    });

    console.log('App exiting...');
});
```

It's not the most elegant code but it works, if I wrap the co-function in a loop I can download as many as I want (the end-goal is to have this API receive a JSON list of image URLs).  What I cannot do however is return the results of the piping to the caller, the app will always exit before that process is complete.  I thought wrapping the function call in a yield would be the answer...but no.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you're inside a generator function (a Koa handler), you use `yield` to wait.

The general pattern is to extract your async logic into a function that returns a promise, and then you yield it inside your route.

The first problem with your code is that you never use `reject` and `resolve` in the promise to transition it to a finished/errored state. The promise never knows when it's finished. Yielding it will never return control back to the route, which is probably why you nested it in another `co` process.

Here, I fix it so that it `resolve()`s on completion and `reject(err)`s on error. Note: yielding a promise that hits a `reject(err)` path will throw an exception (`err`) that you can try/catch at the call site.

```
var pipeRequest = function(url, filepath) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    request.get(url)
      .pipe(fs.createWriteStream(filepath))
      .on('finish', function() { resolve() })
      .on('error', function(err) { reject(err) })
  });
};
```

The second problem I see is that you're nesting a `co` process in your route which is going to ensure that the route never waits on the `yield` inside it.

A Koa handler is already run inside a `co` process. Just replace that whole co block with a top-level `yield pipeRequest(url, filepath)` once you've implemented my resolve/reject changes above.